REACT NATIVE padding issue white spaces on top and bottom of the IOS screen (notch area) even if the SafeAreaView is not given
I am new to ReactNative development and I couldn't figure out the white spaces that occur on top and bottom of the screen even without the SafeAreaView component. I am testing this on ExpoGo app on my mobile.
import React from "react";
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import Footer from "../components/Footer";
import LittleLemonHeader from "../components/LittleLemon";
import WelcomeScreen from "../components/WelcomeScreen";
import MenuItems from "../components/MenuItems";

export default function Index() {
  return (
    //<View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#495E57" }}>
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <LittleLemonHeader />
      <MenuItems />
      <Footer />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#495E57",
    padding: 0, // Ensure no padding in the container
    margin: 0,
  },
});


If the <SafeAreaView> isn't working correctly, you should manualy set the padding.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

require "sinatra"
require "dotenv/load"
require "net/http"
require "json"

link italic bold `code
